# How to add data from a csv to a new table in SQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a CSV like this:

```
no_orden    codigo_producto cantidad_orden  precio_cada nombre_producto linea_productos descr   precio_compra   fecha_orden no_cliente  nombre_cliente  tlf direccion   ciudad  estado  codigo_postal   pais
0   10100   S18_1749    30  136.00  1917 Grand Touring Sedan    Vintage Cars    Our Vintage Car models realistically portray a...   86.70   2003-01-06  363 Online Diecast Creations Co.    6035558647  2304 Long Airport Avenue    Nashua  NH  62005   USA
1   10100   S18_2248    50  55.09   1911 Ford Town Car  Vintage Cars    Our Vintage Car models realistically portray a...   33.30   2003-01-06  363 Online Diecast Creations Co.    6035558647  2304 Long Airport Avenue    Nashua  NH  62005   USA
```

it have 17 columns

So with that, I convert this csv in a data frame

```
import pandas as pd

concesionario = pd.read_csv("Coches/ventas.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame(concesionario)
```

and I want to create to SQL tables. The first one is this:

```
cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Pedido
(no_orden INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
codigo_producto CHAR(20), 
cantidad_orden INT NOT NULL, 
precio_cada FLOAT (10), 
nombre_producto TEXT NOT NULL, 
linea_productos TEXT NOT NULL, 
descr TEXT NOT NULL, 
precio_compra FLOAT (10), 
fecha_orden DATE, 
no_cliente INT NOT NULL)

''')
```

and it works, so now I have this table save it

Now I want to pass the Information of the columns in the data frame to the new table and I put this:

```
for index,row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('''
                INSERT INTO Pedido (no_orden, codigo_producto, cantidad_orden, precio_cada, nombre_producto, linea_productos, descr, precio_compra, fecha_orden, no_cliente)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
                ''', 
                row.no_orden,
                row.codigo_producto, 
                row.cantidad_orden,
                row.precio_cada,
                row.nombre_producto,
                row.linea_productos,
                row.descr,
                row.precio_compra,
                row.fecha_orden,
                row.no_cliente 
        
                )
conn.commit()
```

and give me this error

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

maybe it is another way to add the info but I don't know my error

thank you for all

Comment: Reading a .csv file and insert it row by row is too much overhead. Use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE instead.

Comment: I know it is too much work, and for this reason I want to make a loop or any other type of code. I don't understand your "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE instead". I have a personal data base.

Comment: You are not passing any parameter to `cursor.execute` just the query. Try passing `row` as second argument.

Comment: yeah, I edited the post with the new code, but it give me the same error

Answer (score 0):

pandas dataframes have the [`df.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method, which might be suitable for what you want to do.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(YOUR_DB)

cols = ['no_orden', 'codigo_producto', 'cantidad_orden', 'precio_cada', 'nombre_producto', 'linea_productos', 'descr', 'precio_compra', 'fecha_orden', 'no_cliente']

df_upload = df[cols] # pick the columns you're interested in
with engine.connect() as con:
    df_upload.to_sql('Pedido', con)
```

But really @georg-richter is right - this is a situation where python and pandas is pretty unnecessary overhead - Depending on the SQL you're using there are lots of better ways to load values from a file.

Comment: and what are the other ways to load values from a file?

Comment: it depends what version of SQL you are using.
[Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)
[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: and your code give me this error " AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'

Comment: i am using a Jupyter notebook in python for making this

Comment: What are you using for `YOUR_DB`?

Comment: i understand your_db like name of my dataframe.